# Spring data JPA with rest: how to filter out a subset of records in a one-to-many mapping

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I am a bad java programmer...
Maybe I am designing my database in the wrong way. Any clue is welcome.

Now it's like this:
table1 named node has:
id
info
update-date

table2 named node_records has:
id
node_id(reverse reference to node)
value
create-date

I want to select all records in node_records that node_record.node_id = node.id and node_record.create-date = node.update-date.

In Node.java:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = NodeRecord.class, mappedBy = "node")
List<NodeRecord> nodeRecord;
```

In NodeRecord.java:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
Node node;
```

For now, I can select all records where record.node_id = node.id, but I searched for hours trying to find out how to select records that also satisfies condition record.creat-date = node.updated-date.

Answer (score 0):

- Use @Query annotation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Or

- Use Spring data custom implements: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Answer (score 0):

Dialects can help here, There are database specific date function which support specific dialects, like:
If your database is mysql so you can use "date" function in your Query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from NodeRecord  as nr join nr.node as n where date(nr.createdDate) = date(n.updateDate)");
```

If you are using oracle then can use `TRUNC` function in your query.

Comment: Your query returns a list of `Node`.